# Compare API access parameters from Android and iOS application

Tags: api, http, automation, compare, packet-sniffers

We are developing an android port of an existing iOS application (made by same company and accessing same server API). The server API is huge and contain many optional parameters. The developer can tend to skip the optional parameters... that may tend the application to behave slightly differently in certain use-cases.

Manually scanning of code of all such parameters for different situations is tedious and still error prone. Is here any way to do it with softwares.

Like sniff http calls from both APIs and take differences. Anyway to automate it to some extent even if not completely?

I guess its a common problem for companies maintaining apps for different platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like Fiddler. Its a little old and something I haven't used recently, but might just work for you.

More info [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2011/12/06/configuring-fiddler-to-capture-web-traffic-from-an-iphone-ipad-device/).

Comment: Hey thanks, but how its different from HTTPScoop or Wireshark etc? is here a possibility to compare http requests automatically from two application sessions? (assume I run apps in exact same manner)

Comment: You can't really compare them using the tools. That's something you'll need to do manually once you have a list of all requests made by the apps.

Comment: Thanks.. your answer didn't solve my issue though it give me good idea about proxy :-)

btw, I was looking for solution on mac.